# What changes should be done to the following program to convert into multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading

Task - 1 - MultiThreading:

1. We need to change endpoint-simple.py to multi-threading.
2. We are replicating the string 'mystr' 5000 times in a list. Then we are merging a list into a single string.
3. We need to split this list of 5000 items into 5 lists (each with 1000 records).
4. Now write these 5 lists on disk in parallel using 5 threads and notedown the total time.

endpoint-simple.py -

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET']) 
def hello():
    return {"response": "success"}


@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST']) 
def foo():
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    
    l=[data['mystr']]*5000
    mystr=" ".join(l)
    
    for i in range(10000):
        with open(f"tmp/file_{i}.txt", "w") as f:
                  f.write(mystr)
    
    
    return {"response": "success"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000)
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. What did you try?

Comment: I used the 5 functions to run individually, but I am not able to store the output from those functions to a global variable. I don't know wheres the problem.

Comment: To store variables globally you have to use `global` so lets say you have a variable `value = 1` then you would put `global value` on the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

To multithread I would recommend using this python library

```py
import thread
```

This should be a standard python library. Its syntax is to be used as:

```py
thread.start_new_thread ( function, args[, kwargs] )
```

I'll include a short example down below and it's output.

```py
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

The output you will receive:

```
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:17 2009
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:19 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:19 2009
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:21 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:23 2009
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:23 2009
Thread-1: Thu Jan 22 15:42:25 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:27 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:31 2009
Thread-2: Thu Jan 22 15:42:35 2009
```

Although it is very effective for low-level threading, but the thread module is very limited compared to the newer threading module.